# How to close an adjacent drop down when opening another

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to set up a list of filters for a results page. But I only want one list of the three active at a time. I'm using jQuery to show/hide the lists.

Here's a stripped down version of what I'm working on.
https://jsfiddle.net/JeffSydor/bgpw9x60/

```js
$('.dropMenu ul').css('display', 'none');
$('.dropMenu').click(function() {
  var thisMenu = $(this).children('.listName'),
    thisList = $(this).children('ul');
  if (thisMenu.not('.open')) {
    thisMenu.toggleClass('open');
    thisList.slideToggle();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="lists">
  <div class="dropMenu">
    <div class="listName">
      <p class="authors">Contributors</p>
      <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="author">name01</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="author">name02</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="dropMenu">
    <div class="listName">
      <p class="categories">Categories</p>
      <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="category">cat01</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="category">cat02</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="dropMenu">
    <div class="listName">
      <p class="tags">Tags</p>
      <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="tag">tag01</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="tag">tag02</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to look for other open menus and close them when clicking on any of the others.

I've looked into preventDefaults too, but it doesn't make any sense to me or if it would work.

Comment: Sounds like you're reinventing the accordion menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work, and you won't even need the `if` statement.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('.dropMenu ul').css('display', 'none');

  $('.dropMenu').click(function(){
    $('.dropMenu').not($(this)).children('.listName').removeClass('open');
    $('.dropMenu').not($(this)).children('ul').slideUp();
    $(this).children('.listName').toggleClass('open');
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="lists">
  <div class="dropMenu">
    <div class="listName">
      <p class="authors">Contributors</p>
      <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="author">name01</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="author">name02</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="dropMenu">
    <div class="listName">
      <p class="categories">Categories</p>
      <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="category">cat01</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="category">cat02</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="dropMenu">
    <div class="listName">
      <p class="tags">Tags</p>
      <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="tag">tag01</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="tag">tag02</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I understand what is going on here now. If children named ".listName" of ".dropMenu" items, of which are also not this clicked item, then remove the class ".open". Same with the slideup command.

Is this a correct analysis?

Comment: @JeffSydor Yes, since it's not the one being clicked on, we want to remove the styling and slide it back up.

Answer (score 1):

You can just slide all of them up and then slide the clicked one down.

```
 $('.dropMenu').click(function(){
    let lists = $('.dropMenu .listName');
    $('.dropMenu .listName').removeClass('.open');
    $('.dropMenu ul').slideUp();

    $(this).children('.listName').addClass('open');
    $(this).children('ul').slideDown();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Select the ones that are opened and close them before opening a new one

```
$('.dropMenu ul').css('display', 'none');
$('.dropMenu').click(function() {
  var thisMenu = $(this).children('.listName'),
    thisList = $(this).children('ul');
  if (thisMenu.not('.open')) {
    $('.dropMenu .open').removeClas('open')
    thisMenu.toggleClass('open');
    thisList.slideToggle();
  }
});
```